# Problem with Array to string conversion in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to upload multiple images and save the filenames to the database but I get an error Array to string conversion Error in Laravel. What am I doing wrong?

```
public function imageupload(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
                'images.*' => 'image'
        ]);
        $files = [];
        $path="storage/uploads/";
        if($request->hasfile('images'))
         {
            foreach($request->file('images') as $file)
            {
                $name = time().rand(1,50).'.'.$file->extension();
                $file->move($path, $name);  
                $files[] = $name;  
            }
         }
         //dd($files);//here I am able to see all files
           $img=new albumImages;
           $img->album_id=$request->albumId;
           $img->path=$files;
           $img->save();
  
        return back()->with('message', 'Images are successfully uploaded');
    }
```

Comment: What line the error occurs??

Comment: @Elias  $img->path=$files; here is where the error is

Comment: Because path os an atray as you stated on dd.  You want to store multiple pahs on one albumImages model? If so you need to ad an array cast to the path field

Answer (score 1):

you need to cast the array to JSON string on your own: `$img->path=json_encode($files);` or add `path` attribute as json cast in model like this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: a good solution and I am able to save but the file name appears as ["165078899740.png","165078899727.png","165078899747.png"] in one row. I am using relationship one to many i.e an album has many images. I thought it will be three rows but with the same album id.

Comment: why don't you save it inside foreach loop? `$img->path=$name;`

Comment: @Chinch thanks for the response it works but only adds one row and saves a single  image. I have even added $img->save(); in and outside the for loop but only save one image.

Comment: you have to create new instance, assign attributes and save inside foreach which mean the whole part `$img=new albumImages; ... $img->save();` is inside foreach